# Dimension is MonthYear: How to count for the previous month?

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I have the following data (just one table):

[image]

And on sheet I want to create a table that will have `MonthYear` as dimension and two measures:

- `Current`: Counts distinct users that had `Activity = "Payment"`. Expression for this is:
  `Count({<[Activity]={'Payment'}>} distinct [%_user_id])` and it works fine.
- `Previous`: Counts distinct users that had `Activity = "Payment"` **during previous month**. For example, if the value of the `MonthYear` dimension is `Feb 2023`, then it should show count for the `Jan 2023`. Or, for `Jan 2023` it should show count for `Dec 2022` ...

[image]

Do you know what the expression for the `Previous` measure would be?

I tried this:

```
Count({<MonthYear={'$(=Date(AddMonths(MonthYear, -1), 'MMM YYYY'))'}, [Activity]={'Payment'}>} distinct [%_user_id])
```

but it does not work.

Maybe such a measure is not possible in this particular case?

Comment: It will depend on if the MonthYear field is stored as a formatted date or stored as a string. What you are trying now is using it as a formatted date. Perhaps try MonthYear={'$(=text(Date(AddMonths(MonthYear, -1), 'MMM YYYY')))'}

Answer (score 0):

Preparing some dummy data for myself:

```
Data:
Load *, 
    Date(MonthStart([Fact Date]), 'MMM YYYY') as [Month Year], 
    RowNo() as %_fact_id
Inline [
%_user_id, Activity, "Fact Date" 
1, Registration,    2023-01-01 
1, Payment,         2023-01-30 
2, Registration,    2023-01-10 
2, Payment,         2023-01-14 
2, Payment,         2023-02-23 
3, Registration,    2023-01-04 
3, Payment,         2023-01-26 
4, Registration,    2023-02-07 
5, Registration,    2023-02-19 
5, Payment,         2023-02-20 
5, Payment,         2023-02-23 
];
```

You can use this expression using `Aggr()` and `Above()` instead of `Previous()`

```
Aggr(Above(Count({<[Activity]={'Payment'}>} distinct [%_user_id])), [Month Year])
```

Returning this result:

[image]